# Is Java UTF-8 Charset exception possible?

Tags: java, exception, utf-8, character-encoding

Can Java possibly throw `UnsupportedEncodingException` when using `"UTF-8"` encoding, or I can safely suppress it's throwing?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As McDowell noted in a comment to [templatetypdef's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049524/is-java-utf-8-charset-exception-possible/5049540#5049540): If you use a `Charset` object when you instantiate a new `String` instead of passing the name of the charset, you don't have to deal with an `UnsupportedEncodingException` or any other checked exception:

```
byte[] bytes = ...;

// Requires you to handle UnsupportedEncodingException
String s1 = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");

// Doesn't require you to handle any checked exceptions
String s2 = new String(bytes, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

It's an inconsistency in Java's standard library that we have to live with...

Note that `Charset.forName(...)` can throw exceptions (`IllegalCharsetNameException`, `IllegalArgumentException`, `UnsupportedCharsetException`), but these are all unchecked exceptions, so you don't have to catch or re-throw them yourself.

**edit** - Since Java 7 there's class `java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets` which has constants for frequently used character encodings. Example:

```
String s3 = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Answer (score 13):

According to [the Javadoc for `Charset`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html), every Java implementation must support UTF-8, along with a few other charsets.  Therefore, I think you can safely suppress the exception; unless you have a non-compliant Java implementation, this shouldn't be able to fail.

Comment: Also, if you can use the `Charset` class instead of a straight string literal, you shouldn't need to handle `UnsupportedEncodingException`.

Answer (score 8):

The most simple way is to create a UTF-8 charset constant. Then you don't have to catch the UnsupportedEncodingException again and again:

```
public class Charsets {
    public static final Charset UTF_8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
}
```

Edit (2014-04):

With Java 7 you don't have to create your own constant. You can simply use [`StandardCharsets.UTF_8`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html) instead.

Comment: Very sensible.  Oracle should add constants like this to the Charset class for all the JVM guaranteed charsets.   edit: Nevermind, I see they finally did in java 7.

Answer (score 6):

It's supposed to be present in every Java runtime, so it is reasonable to re-throw a runtime exception if it is missing. I wouldn't call that "suppressing," though. To me, suppressing means catching the exception and pretending it didn't happen; not sure how you'd proceed if the encoding is missing.

Answer (score 5):

It depends what you mean by "safe" and "suppress".

I'd be tempted to catch the exception and throw an unchecked exception (or `AssertionError`) in its place.  The chances are that your application will never experience this.  But who knows ... someone might run it on some non-conformant platform in which UTF-8 was not available.  And it costs almost nothing to do this ... especially since you have to "do something" with the original exception.

Answer (score -1):

i Have used the below line of code and it worked for me

## Old code

byte[] hash = digest.digest(input.getBytes("UFT-8"));

## Updated Code

byte[] hash = digest.digest(input.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));